# postgres is not correctly incrementing my id which is of serial data-type

Tags: python, postgresql

there are 500 records in my database and when I delete the id =5 and then try to re-insert the same record it is not updating the sequence correctly. It inserts the new record where id = 505 however my largest id was 500. 
I am also updating sequencing before and after transaction with the following query:
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name', 'id'), max(id)) FROM table_name;

Still, it is incrementing the sequence not correctly.

id bigserial primary key NOT NULL

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Deleting a row for which as sequence has been used to populate a column does NOT update the sequence.

If you need a gapless ordering number you cannot use a sequence.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html which says:

> Because nextval and setval calls are never rolled back, sequence
>   objects cannot be used if "gapless" assignment of sequence numbers is
>   needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive
>   locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much
>   more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions
>   need sequence numbers concurrently.

Comment: Hello @pifor, actually I am new to postgres and does not get what you are actually trying to say because when I try to insert new values then the incrementation is working fine, but why it is not inserting the record which I am re-inserting at id=501.

Comment: Post your detailed scenario including BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK statements if any.